# How do I get the number of rows of a datatool table?

Tags: datatool

I create a table as follows:

```
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{MaTable}
\end{document}
```

This table may be filled with several occurrences of

```
\DTLnewrow{MaTable}
\DTLnewdbentry{MaTable}{key}{value}
```

My question is: How can I get the total number of rows of the table?

Answer (score 8):

The answer is just

```
\DTLrowcount{Table}
```

I'm sorry. I was looking for it in the documentation, but i was reading **after** the section "creating a new database" ... :(

Comment: No need to apologize.  We've all done this. And it's fine to answer your own question (and accept it once the time limit allows you to.)

Comment: yes ... in my case, it gave me the opportunity to answer a question ! which happens to me not so often ;)